# merge and get max value from two different datatables in R

Tags: r, data.table

I've 2 different data.tables. I need to merge and get max value based on a row values. The examples of two tables are given as Input below and expected output shown below.

**Input**

**Table 1**

```
X   A   B
A   3   
B   4   6
C   5   
D   9   12
```

**Table 2**

```
X   A   B    
A   1   5
B   6   8
C   7   14
D   5   
E   1   1
F   2   3
G   5   6
```

**Expected Output:**

```
X   A   B
A   3   5
B   6   8
C   7   14
D   9   12
E   1   1
F   2   3
G   5   6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `rbind` the two datasets and do a group by `max`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(tbl1, tbl2))[, lapply(.SD, max, na.rm = TRUE), X]
#   X A  B
#1: A 3  5
#2: B 6  8
#3: C 7 14
#4: D 9 12
#5: E 1  1
#6: F 2  3
#7: G 5  6
```

---

If we are using `base R`, then use `aggregate` after `rbind`ing the datasets

```
aggregate(.~ X, rbind(tbl1, tbl2), max, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
```

NOTE: Assume that the 'A', 'B' columns are numeric and blanks are `NA`

#### data

```
tbl1 <- structure(list(X = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), A = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 9L
 ), B = c(NA, 6L, NA, 12L)), .Names = c("X", "A", "B"), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -4L))

tbl2 <- structure(list(X = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), A = c(1L, 
6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L), B = c(5L, 8L, 14L, NA, 1L, 3L, 6L)), .Names = c("X", 
"A", "B"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can I understand how we can handle if 'A', 'B' columns are Date and blanks are NA. I tried the same but it's not working

Comment: @PraveenKumar  If it is `Date` too, it would work assuming that the Date is `Date` class. i.e. `max(as.Date(c('2017-01-01', '2016-01-01', NA)), na.rm = TRUE)#
[1] "2017-01-01"`

Comment: I tried max for Date class.. I'm getting warning message as "No non-missing values found in at least one group. Returning '-Inf' for such groups to be consistent with base"

Comment: @PraveenKumar  I guess for some groups you have only NA.  In that case, use a `if/else` loop i.e. `rbindlist(list(tbl1, tbl2))[, lapply(.SD, function*(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else max(x, na.rm = TRUE)), X]`